# How to check if observable countdown timer has completed?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ionic3

I have a simple countdown timer in angular 4

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

countDown;
counter = 60;
enableButton:boolean = false;

this.countDown = Observable.timer(0,1000).take(this.counter).map(() => --
 this.counter);
```

I want to make enableButton boolean true when this observable has been completed.

How should I write that code? Please Help

Here is a plunker link, which I am using in my project
https://plnkr.co/edit/TWMIEd1UykUdUC37qyFK?p=preview

Comment: I just updated my answer with your plunker

Comment: @Michael -- see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45718118/561731 relies on using the observable scan instead of updating the components counter.

Comment: @Neal -- I accept your answer too, thank you very much, for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @MichaelJoshua you can only "accept" one answer in this system ;-) make your choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the view:

```
<button [disabled]="counter !== 0">OK</button>
```

and in the class:

```
  countDown;
  counter = 10; // change accordingly
  tick = 1000;
  constructor() {
  this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
      .take(this.counter)
      .map(() => --this.counter)
  }
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eNhUSbbP2bRX3XeNISBe?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day

Comment: Comments like this make my day :) You are very welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize scan and async to your advantage:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ` 
    <div>
      <h1>Countdown timer</h1>
      <h2>{{countDown | async}}</h2>
      
      <button [disabled]="(countDown | async) === 0">My button</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  
  countDown;
  counter = 10;
  
  constructor() {
    
    this.countDown = Observable.timer(0,1000)
      .scan((current, next) => this.counter - next)
      .takeWhile(counter => counter >= 0);
  }
}
```

Here is the live version: https://plnkr.co/edit/bKESzNK1wqbtPmQk4TUT?p=preview

So instead of updating the global counter you use scan to keep count of a local version (as the timer returns numbers in sequence)

### OLD ANSWER

You can utilize the [`.takeWhile`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html) operator

```
this.countDown = Observable.timer(0,1000)
    .take(this.counter)
    .map(() => --this.counter)
    .takeWhile(counter => counter >= 0);
```

Here is the updated plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Z6K5Yt2tDS4MKbgIoujc?p=preview

You actually do not need the `.take` and can just do this:

```
this.countDown = Observable.timer(0,1000)
  .map(() => this.counter--)
  .takeWhile(counter => counter >= 0);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/L38t3LYON9DszW5N2MjA?p=preview

Comment: Still not working as OP's wish I think.See this: https://plnkr.co/edit/VW47EZDnRPzvUX0hP3Rs?p=preview

Comment: @Sampath why are you subscribing? that makes the aync in the template no longer work

Comment: But he needs to enable this variable no `enableButton`? How can he do it without `subscribing` it?

Comment: Thanks @Sampath :-D

Comment: You need to do small correction on your answer.OP needs to `enable` the button after the count down has been completed.

Comment: True, but easily reversible if the OP needs. Don't need to write all of the code for the OP ;-)

Answer (score -1):

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html third argument

You may do it like this:

```
this.countDown = Observable
  .timer(0, 1000)
  .take(this.counter)
  .map(() => --this.counter);

this.countDown.subscribe(() => {}, () => {}, () => (this.enableButton = true))
```

Or like this:

```
<button *ngIf="!(countDown | async)"><button>
<button *ngIf="this.counter"><button>
```